# Upload periodically drops off when transferring data over LAN

Tags: hard-drive, linux-mint, lan, freenas

I recently built a FreeNAS box with the intention of using it to store all of the digital junk I've accumulated over the years. It's been doing that pretty well, however when transferring files over to it I noticed that the transfer speed periodically and frequently drops down to 0 before increasing again.

[image: Screenshot taken from System Monitor on Linux Mint]

Each file ranges in size from ~300 MBs to 2+ GBs.

My question is then: What's causing this?

My best guess was that maybe this is essentially just showing the seek time on the source hard drive, but after googling around I haven't been able to find any info one way or another.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that it is a congestion-control mechanism, though at what point in the stack is unknown. Switches and routers perform congestion control at the datalink layer with back-off  algorithms, and IP responds to congestion with Source Quench messages (over ICMP), and TCP does this by adjusting the windowing size downward, so that the sender has to wait for a response more often before proceeding. Since your spikes and vallies seem to be evenly distributed, it probably isn't TCP flow control. I would expect that to have fewer less steep valleys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, since I realized I can actually pretty easily test whether or not it's the seek time by sticking a bunch of files in a tar archive and moving that.  That results in the [following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFVPX.png), which would definitely seem to indicate the problem is the seek time for finding the next file.